# Finding files that don't have a wildcard

Tags: java, file, csv

So I have csvs:

R-15_A.csv

R-16_A.csv

R-17_A.csv

R-15_B.csv

R-15_A_Processed.csv

R-15_B_Processed.csv

R-16_A_Processed.csv

R-17_A_Processed.csv

Been using commons.io's wildcardfilefilter but am confused at the filter.

So if I wanted to get a list of files that are A but **not processed** what would I use for the filter?

```
File dir = new File(".");
        FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("filter?");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
        for(File f:files)
        {
            log.info("service2: "+f.getName());
        }
        log.info("service2: size "+files.length);
```

Comment: Doesn't "*A.csv" work?

Comment: huh... that works perfectly lol. Thanks! Wonder how I missed that.

Comment: Reposted as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*A.csv" should match 'A' but not 'Processed'